# Angular2 and Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

Here is the situation: I'm using async. script loading with systemJS (by scripts, I mean jQuery, Angular2, ...). Now I would like to implement Turbolinks into this. Everything works just fine, but my angular component is rendered only the first time. If I use Turbolinks to see next page, my component is not rendering. No errors in object inspector and in source code is only this:

```
<search-app></search-app>
```

I've tired test in object inspector but after second page lead this is only HTML tag.

Here are my loading scripts in SystemJS in Head tag on my page:

```
System.config({

            meta: {
                '/bundles/frontall': { format: 'global' },
                '/bundles/raphael': { format: 'global' },
                '/bundles/zopim': { format: 'global' },
                '/bundles/angular2': { format: 'global' }
            },

            packages: {
                'angular': {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },

                'angular2': {
                    format: 'global',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },

                'rxjs': {
                    format: 'global',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            },

            paths: {
                'angular2/*': 'scripts/angular2/*',
                'rxjs/*': 'scripts/rxjs/*'
            }
        });


         System.import('/bundles/frontall').then(function () {
            Promise.all([
                System.import('/bundles/zopim'),
                System.import('/bundles/raphael'),
                System.import('bundles/angular2'),
                @RenderSection("asyncScripts", required: false)
            ]).then(function () {

            System.import('angular/searchApp');
        });
```

In the frontAll bundle is file site.js, where I re-initing all components:

```
function componentInit() {

//init material design
$.material.init();

//init texarea autosize
autosize($('textarea'));

//init parallax
$('.parallax-window').parallax();

//init smooth scroll
//SmoothScroll();

//init css3 animate it
$.animateIt();
$.doTimeout();
$.animateItInit();

$.srSmoothscroll({
    step: 80,
    speed: 90,
    ease: 'linear',
    target: $('body'),
    container: $(window)
});  
}

$(function () {
    componentInit();

});

$(document).on('page:load', function () {
    componentInit();
});
```

Angular 2 version is beta 7. Does anybody know where is the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, solved! I need to add  `jQuery(function () {
    bootstrap(searchApp, [ElementRef, TournamentSearchService]);

});

jQuery(document).on('page:load', function () {
    bootstrap(searchApp, [ElementRef, TournamentSearchService]);
}); ` to my angular2 app and it works. :-))

Comment: great, please create an answer and accept your own answer so this question gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add this to my angular2 app and it works:

```
jQuery(function () { 
    bootstrap(searchApp, [ElementRef, TournamentSearchService]); 
}); 
jQuery(document).on('page:load', function () { 
    bootstrap(searchApp, [ElementRef, TournamentSearchService]); 
});
```